# Basic question related to relay operation

Tags: relay, inductor, electromagnetism, magnetic-flux

Electromechanical relays are generally based on the principle​ that electromagnets(due to supply current ) attracts armature of relay which is made up of ferromagnetic material (because ferromagnetic materials are attracted towards high magnetic field density region) and close or open the switch depending on design.

My question is -

Can we make a slight change in the principle  of operation of relay by using a low resistance non ferromagnetic conductor as armature of relay and due to low resistance a high  current induced (Eddy current) in the armature when we turn on or off the supply and a transient high repulsive force(lenz law) acts on the armature and hence we can open or close the switch ?

Or

there is any practical problem in this operation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can we make a slight change in the principle of operation of relay by
> using a low resistance non ferromagnetic conductor as armature of
> relay and due to low resistance a high current induced (Eddy current)
> in the armature when we turn on or off the supply and a transient high
> repulsive force(lenz law) acts on the armature and hence we can open
> or close the switch ?*

You can make things move (and slow down) by using eddy current induction but, in your example, this only works for the small period of time that the changing magnetic field in a relay coil lasts. Maybe a few tens of milliseconds.

> *Or there is any practical problem in this operation ?*

Once a stable magnetic field is set-up, eddy currents disappear and the thing that moved (if held in neutral with a spring as per a relay) then returns back to its neutral position.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a time where you can use a mechanical solution in conjunction with an electrical phenomenon.

You can actuate things using eddy current, but holding the armature would not be possible with just electricity.

Here is where a mechanical "[Detent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detent)" will be useful, a detent is a device which prevents a state change via some physical method. In your case, you can hold the detent on the armature pulled and pushed position.

You need to make sure that the "Overcoming" current required to change states is calculated and achievable, you also need to make sure that this value is higher than the signal's noise.

As far as I know, they probably don't use this principle because smarter people with better resources found it infeasible, but this still seems like a good thought experiment.